# Ransack: using age instead of date of birth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I would like to use ransack to build an advanced search function for a page with `Users`.
I have a small method to calculate age from date of birth:

```
def age(dob)
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

That works on normal display (`as in age(@user.date_of_birth)`)

But when using search_form_for I cannot do the same:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_users_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :date_of_birth_gteq, "Age between" %>
        <%= f.text_field :date_of_birth_gteq %>
        <%= f.label :date_of_birth_gteq, "and" %>
        <%= f.text_field :date_of_birth_lteq %>
    </div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
 <% end %>
```

My question is: how can I use age in my search instead of date of birth?

Answer (score 5):

Add a Scope like below to find the date for the given age.

```
scope :age_between, lambda{|from_age, to_age|
  if from_age.present? and to_age.present?
    where( :date_of_birth =>  (Date.today - to_age.to_i.year)..(Date.today - from_age.to_i.year) )
  end
}
```

For ransacke syntax:

```
ransacker :age, :formatter => proc {|v| Date.today - v.to_i.year} do |parent|
  parent.table[:date_of_birth]
end
```

In view

```
<%= f.text_field :age_gteq %>
```

Comment: Should I use it like this? <%= f.label :age_between_gteq, "Age between" %>
  <%= f.text_field :age_between_gteq %>. That didn't work. I get this error: undefined method `age_between_gteq' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search

Comment: Thanks! It works, but not completely. In order to calculate age the year is not enough, you also need the month and the  day, so I don't quite understand how to obtain this information and use it in ransacker. So right now this function is not really accurate because it only works by the year

Comment: You don't need to consider month or day. Because the date is generated based on the `currency_date - years`, So it only reduce the years and keep the current day and month.

Comment: You are right, sorry about the mixup. However when I do use the answer above three things happen:

Comment: 1. the _lteq field acts like _gteq field and vice versa (meaning, instead of 88..92, the range that "works" is 92..88). 2. _lteq and _gteq function as _lt and _gt. For example, for a 1..27 range, the application does not display an entry of a 27 year old person. 3. The scope doesn't seem to have any effect. When I disable it, it works the same way. I cannot seem to find good examples or explainations of using ransacker like this anywhere. Thanks for your help

Comment: @TimmyOnRails I'm having the same problem as you described on above comment. Did you manage to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not know ransacker personally and tried to use ransacker but couldn't find any thing that could check the predicate passed in. 
Hence I believe it's better to use scopes to do it.

```
def self.age_lteq(age)
  start_birth_year = Date.today.year - age
  where('date_of_birth >= ?', Date.new(start_birth_year))
end

def self.age_gteq(age)
  birth_year = Date.today.year - age
  end_of_birth_year = Date.new(birth_year + 1) - 1
  where('date_of_birth <= ?', end_of_birth_year)
end

private

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  %i(age_lteq age_gteq)
end

# In views just do the following (ransack default grouping queries is by AND)
# https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#grouping-queries-by-or-instead-of-and
<%= f.input :age_lteq %>
<%= f.input :age_gteq %>
```

@siddick answer is cool, but the logic of `lteq` acts like `gt` and `gteq` acts like `lt`.
I myself is starting out ruby and rails recently. So do tell me if I did anything wrong. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on @siddick answer (which works perfectly). You now need to white list scopes that ransack offers. In the case of the answer from @siddick you need to do this:

```
def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  %i(age_between)
end
```

For more info see the docs - https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#using-scopesclass-methods