# Undefined method error for filtering by age using Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

I am trying to filter results by age using ransack, but ransack is giving me an undefined method error. I have the Users DOB in my database and in my users model I have an age method that calculates the age of the user. It works perfectly fine and I am able to call the users age like this:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.age
```

Now for ransack I have the following in my controller:

```
  def index
   @search = User.search(params[:q])
   @users = @search.result
  end
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :age_gteq, "Ages:" %> <%= f.text_field :age_gteq %>
    <%= f.label :age_lteq, "to" %> <%= f.text_field :age_lteq %>
    <%=f.submit "Filter", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
undefined method `age_gteq' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

I am sure I'd get the same error for `age_lteq`

Comment: did you add `age` to `attr_accessible`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I wasn't sure I had to since it is a method and not an attribute of the User stored in the database.

Comment: sorry, not age, but `age_gteq` and `are_lteq`. i'm not sure how to use ransack, but that should be a hint

Comment: No, I dont think you need to add that to attr_accessible.Ransack provides _gteq and _lteq for your model attributes.

Comment: ok, did you try than just to put `age` in the `attr_accessible`. I guess there's the problem, since your calling ransack on a method and not on a model attribute

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but didn't help. Here is a very similar issue, but I can't seem to make any sense out of it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021662/ransack-using-age-instead-of-date-of-birth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't work, because currently Ransack only works with database columns. In the end Ransack is just a sophisticated SQL query generator.

Think about this example:

```
User.where('age >= ?', 30)
```

What would a SQL query look like?

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE age >= 30
```

Even if Ransack would pipe through such conditions on normal non-database attributes, the SQL would still be wrong. (Since there is no `age` column)

One solution would be to use the original date-of-birth column in your form and use some Javascript to allow the user to enter age numbers instead of dates. For example by listening to the `onsubmit` event and modify the `input`'s content.

**Update 2014-01-08:**

There is another possibility to make this work. Add this to your `User` model:

```
ransacker :age do
  Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(
     'DATE_PART('year', AGE(NOW(), date_of_birth_column))') 
  # Beware: PostgreSQL specific SQL!
end
```

A "ransacker" needs to return an Arel node which later will be attached to the Arel nodes generated by Ransack.

This allows you to use `age_eq` and all the other Ransack predicates just as it were a regular database column.